# Passing selected value from child to parent windows

Tags: javascript, html

I have some problem, I have 2 buttons, and they have 2 different values and different ids (let say Button A and Button B), and I want to make that when I click button A the value fill is FORM C OR when I clik button B the value fill is FORM C (form C from the window parent and button A and B from the child parent). But in my case if I click button A the passing value to form C is a value from button B.
this is the code :

> parent.html

```
<form method='post' action='' name='f1'>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=550>
<tr>
    <td ><font size="2" face='Verdana'>Your Name</font><input type="text" name="p_name"  size='8'> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here " onClick='window.open("child.php","Ratting", "width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,");'>Click here to open the child window</a> 


</td></tr>
</table></form>
```

> child.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
</head>

<body >

<form name="frm" method="post" action=''>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='250'>


 <tr><td align="center">  Your name <input type="button" name="c_name" value="A" onclick="post_value();">


  </td><td align="center">  Your name <input type="button" name="c_name2" value="B" onclick="post_value();">


  </td>

  </tr>

<script langauge="javascript">
function post_value(){
opener.document.f1.p_name.value = document.frm.c_name.value;
opener.document.f1.p_name.value = document.frm.c_name2.value;
 self.close();
}
</script>
</table></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you need to detect which button is clicked. So I change the behavior of button by passing a signal to the function:

Setting data on buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="c_name" value="A" onclick="post_value('a');">
<input type="button" name="c_name2" value="B" onclick="post_value('b');">
```

receive data on function:

```
function post_value(button){
if (button=="a"){
opener.document.f1.p_name.value = document.frm.c_name.value;
}
if (button=="b"){
opener.document.f1.p_name.value = document.frm.c_name2.value;
}
 self.close();
}
```

As a better solution you can even pass the object (button) itself to the function and extract the value without IF/THEN block and without working with ID:

Setting data on buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="c_name" value="A" onclick="post_value(this);">
<input type="button" name="c_name2" value="B" onclick="post_value(this);">
```

receive data on function:

```
function post_value(button){
opener.document.f1.p_name.value = button.value;
 self.close();
}
```